# Mongoose Required true validation not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying out nodejs and using mongoose to save a document to mangoDB but my validation for name which I set to required : true is not working. Though I have not set name field the document gets saved. Am i missing an thing in my code

```
const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type:String, requried:true},
    author: String,
    tags: [ String ],
    date: Date,
    isPublished: Boolean,
    price: Number
});
const Course = mongoose.model('Course',courseSchema);

async function createCourse() {
    try {
        const course = new Course({
            author: "Srikanth xyz",
            tags: ['express','js'],
            isPublished: true,
            price: 15
        });
        const result = await course.save();
        console.log(result);    
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + error.message);
    }

}
createCourse();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might want to double check "requried" to "required"

Answer (score 4):

Here, the spelling of `required` is wrong. Correct it from 
`requried` to `required`.

Answer (score 0):

I also occur that problem in my nextjs project so drop schema in mongo dB and restart the server after that problem will solve automatically.